# Add ID from URL in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im just starting out with MVC and i'm in the learning phase. I'm currently stuck with this problem. In my soulution i got these two tables.

**TopicTable**
-TopId
-TopName

**ContentTable**
-ContId
-TopId
-Content

I want while i'm in the Topic Detailes-view to be able to create new content.
In the detailes.cshtml file i've added:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Content", "Create", "Content", new { ID = Model.TopicId}, null)` which will display in URL: localhost/Content/Create/1
```

In my ContentController ive got this, and i get this error when submitting "*Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.*"

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(int Id)
        {
            ContentModel content = new ContentModel();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                content.TopId = Id;
                db.ContentModel.Add(content);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            return View(content)
        }
```

The View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.ContentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>JobOfferModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
            </div>
        </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Model:

```
public class Topic
{
[Display(Name = "Id")]
        public virtual int TopicId{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public virtual string TopicName{ get; set; }


}

 public class Content
{
[Display(Name = "Id")]
        [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public virtual int ContentId{ get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "TopicId")]
    public virtual string TopicId{ get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Innihald")]
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }


}
```

So when i'm creating new content the topId value will automaticly be added to the content table.

Would love some help,, Gracias

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code of `Create` view? Also, what's the error you got?

Comment: What errors are you getting? And `@Html.ActionLink()` is a GET, not a POST.

Comment: What is `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)` generating? Your post method only accepts parameter `int ID` so assuming its valid, your not setting any other properties for `ContentModel`. You need to post your GET method and the model.

Comment: Yeah i see that i havfto pass the class object in the parameter. The view is genereted by the scaffolding and i just removed the dropdown that was generated. When i press the actionlink the URL shows http://localhost:54276/Content/Create/1
How can i get the "1" added in my table?

Comment: @Qwerty, You need to post the GET method and your model so we can understand whats happening. Your rendering a form to edit a `ContentModel` but whats the point. You then ignore the model and create a new `ContentModel`, setting only the `TopId` property (debug and check what its value actually is) and try to save it. If `ContentModel` has other properties that are required, then this will fail

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you have any documentation or link to an eksampel so i can learn it? as i said, very new to mvc

Comment: @Qwerty, Just post you model and the GET method and I can show you (do you even have a GET method?)

Comment: Now I'm confused. You have a model named `Content` but in your view and the POST method its `ContentModel`?

Comment: its named Content. copy/paste error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink()` is a call to a GET method. You need a GET to return a view that renders the form, and a POST method to receive and save the form data

```
public ActionResult Create(int ID)
{
  Content model = new Content();
  model.TopicId = ID; // note TopicId should be int, not string
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Content model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // save your model and redirect.
}
```

View (divs etc omitted)

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Content
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TopicId) // for postback
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Content)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
....
```